# Есть ли запрет на определённые аватарки?

Tags: обсуждение, правила, аватар-пользователя

Хочу обновить свою на время на что-то очень коммунистическое(Harry, спасибо за идею). Можно ли выражать политические взгляды через аватарку?

Comment: Мой комментарий не подначка и не осуждение, всё следует из вашей формулировки. Чисто логика. Политические взгляды тоже временно меняете?  Чем вы рискуете в конце, концов? Максимум баном на неделю, да и то  вряд ли рискнут это сделать.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT не припомню, чтобы мы хоть раз бан кому-то выписывали именно за аватар.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ну, почему же, я котам пока не поклоняюсь)).

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica да я не наш сайт имел ввиду, а Enso, там же злобятся в основном на звёзды. А написал, что не `рискнут`, потому что они публично ответили на прямой вопрос - что компания не является антикоммунистической

Comment: @Miron а кто коты то, которым вы не поклоняетесь?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT моя прошлая аватарка

Comment: @Miron почему я о этом смутьяне только сейчас узнаю ?

Comment: @Leks, да, поведение Harry оказалось приятной неожиданностью)) IT - думающее сообщество.

Comment: @Miron а-а-а понятно.. просто имейте ввиду, что не всё помнят наизусть ваш ник и прошлые аватарки :)) А так-то я сразу поставил плюс за вашу позицию, просто формулировка в вопросе очень неудачная

Comment: Я думаю , что можно сделать так: добавить к своему имени says Reinstate Red Star (on hat). А аватарку такую взял уже Harry.

Comment: Ребята, кто топит за коммунизм/социализм, помните, что вы зарабатываете благодаря свободному рынку, то есть капитализму.

Comment: я бы еще подписал says Reinstate Red Star =D

Comment: @AlexDevTime А капиталист зарабатывает на нас. Он лишнее звено, капиталист должен быть замещен профессиональным управляющим. Но, если хотите подискутировать, здесь есть соответствующая беседа для разговоров о политике.

Comment: @AlexDevTime А при социализме программисты не зарабатывали? :) А если вы сейчас расскажете о том, что сейчас они зарабатывают неимоверно много - то я приглашу вас зайти в академический институт и посмотреть на зарплаты в том числе программистов или сисадминов...

Comment: @Harry как раз институт ваш - это государственная собственность. А социализм - это синоним государственной собственности. Так что вы этим аргументом себе подножку подставили. А там, где институты частные, всякие там Гарварды, так там у работников и зарплата соответственная. Так что капитализм рулит и это не моё мнение, а факт статистический.

Comment: @AlexDevTime Ладно, когда-нибудь повзрослеете, столкнетесь с реальной жизнью - тогда просто вспомните... А сейчас с вами спорить просто бесполезно. Как с одним моим другом, на американскую компанию работавшим, до его увольнения :)

Comment: @Harry апелляция к возрасту - не самый конструктивный способ вести беседу =/

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Я не пытаюсь вести беседу. Я высказал свое мнение :) Кстати, у меня в жизни были несколько реальных случаев, когда я только лет через 20 понимал, насколько были правы те, кого я тогда в своей самоуверенности считал недалекими болванами. Кстати, и по нынешней теме тоже :) - в годы перестройки мало кто не переболел либерализмом... Так что это - не апелляция к возрасту, я лишь не хочу тратить время на задачу, в настоящий момент заведомо обреченную, и которая сама разрешится со временем и пониманием. Да, с вами я тоже не спорю, а высказываю мнение, не ожидая ответа :)

Comment: http://inforos.ru/ru/?module=news&action=view&id=10829 - Европа приравняла коммунизм к фашизму

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Основных требований то не так уж и много:

- Не использовать оскорбления.
- Не использовать символику, очевидно оскорбляющую кого-нибудь. Был у нас тут один персонаж, который специально провоцировал людей картинками рейха.

По поводу же коммунистической символики...Я довольно лоялен в этом плане. Сам лично принимать какие-то меры не буду, т.к. довольно спокойно отношусь к сарказму и иронии.

Проблема с тревогами в том, что мы обязаны реагировать на них. Если кого-то аватарка обидит, то мы будем вынуждены какие-то меры принять. Сложность тут в том, что мы исходим из позиции "хороших намерений", т.е. когда человек жалуется, подразумевается, что он не троллит и т.п. И вот когда люди пользуются этой лазейкой и троллят тревогами, вот такие случаи сложно разруливать.

В общем, если резюмировать:

- Если аватарка никого не оскорбляет, то можно использовать.
- Политические взгляды через аватарку? Опять же, если там нет оскорблений.
- Если кто-то пожалуется, то мы будем как-то решать вопрос. Нет, бана не будет. В худшем случае мы попросим сменить аватар.
- В вашем случае проблема в том, как вы поставили вопрос. Мне видится это так, будто вы хотите поставить такую аватарку назло, своего рода провокация. Само это не нарушает правила (хотя вразрез идёт с политикой be nice), но если будут жалобы, то этот нюанс сыграет не в вашу пользу.

**P.S.** в России символика коммунизма/СССР и т.п. в принципе не запрещена. Просто аватарка с Лениным, к примеру, или серп+молот - это уж точно правил не нарушает.

Comment: `видится это так, будто вы хотите поставить такую аватарку назло` от вас это фраза звучит странно (:

Comment: @4per почему же? (¬‿¬ )

Comment: Прочитав ответ я не очень понял как классифицировать символику, которая "очевидно оскорбляет кого-то". На мой взгляд, эта тема более сложная и хотелось бы услышать позицию более четко. Например, если "картинки рейха" могут кого-то оскорбить, то и символ СССР может оскорбить [огромное кол-во людей](https://ru.openlist.wiki). Я считаю, что в этом случае есть два варианта: 1) Разрешить ВСЕ аватарки, которые не противоречат законодательству юрисдикции ruSO. 2) Четко прописать критерии для аватарки, "и волки сыты, и овцы целы". Иные варианты рано или поздно приведут к "сложным случаям".

Comment: @RTK сложно такие вещи формализовать. В примере с рейхом человек явно троллил и аватаркой, и использовал 14/88 в описании, и т.п. Поэтому всё индивидуально рассматривается.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica А можно поставить такую аватарку? Девушка скачет на лошади, но ее не видно(лошади) и она смотрит наверх и кричит вся такая в поту, а снизу голова афроамериканца в напряженному состоянии.  Он схватился за лошадь, когда девушка прорывалась через поселение коренных американцев(¬‿¬ )

Comment: @iluxa1810 зачем нарочито провокационную аватарку ставить? =/

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica да ладно, я рофлю.

Comment: Вы ссылаетесь на "в России символика коммунизма/СССР и т.п. в принципе не запрещена." Но в ответе от модераторов по поволду символики запрещенных в РФ ОУН и УПА мне ответили, что Россия тут ни при чем. Но тогда почему запретили "персонаж, который специально провоцировал людей картинками рейха." - чем он хуже провоцирующих картинками ОУН и УПА?

Comment: @Mikhailo он не только картинками Рейха провоцировал. Я где-то тут уже писал про это. Аватарка с Рейхом лишь один из эпизодов. По поводу законов РФ я зря написал, вероятно. Ну и да, при вынесении решения по участнику, который троллил Рейхом, законы в расчёт не брались.

Answer (score 12):

Я поменял свою аватарку с *Red Star* и [выставил ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340988/154426) - (ответ крайне нейтральный) на известную дискуссию про [коммунистические ушанки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340512/this-star-on-the-warm-welcome-hat-looks-like-a-communist-symbol) - в итоге заработал 6 минусов.

Все мои комментарии также были удалены.

Данный эксперимент показывает, что провокативное именование является раздражителем :)

Что конечно же не останавливает меня от тыканья палкой в сообщество SO, которое на моих глазах из сообщества профессионалов деградирует (или наоборот растет) до сообщества эльфов верхом на розовых пони :)

Comment: Минус поставил в том числе я так как не согласен с вашим мнением. Тема меня не достала. Обиженкой себя не считаю и нахожу это слово довольно...неприятным.

Comment: @Barmaley, в том числе я не согласен с вашей оценкой вашего же ответа - он не нейтральный (как минимум по моему мнению). Если в ваших глазах конкретно я не выгляжу профессионалом и езжу на пони, то, возможно, это и к лучшему.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, я уважаю ваше мнение. Оно ваше и ничье больше. Просто я считаю, что здесь (SO) не то место где это мнение надо выражать: на майдане, в разных политфорумах - пожалуйста, но не здесь  SO не является Трафальгарской площадью - в этом суть моего мнения. В этом смысле мое мнение нейтрально. Не находите?

Comment: нет, не нахожу. это тоже очень полярное мнение, с которым я тоже не согласен, особенно в такой категоричной формулировке.

Comment: Ну вот поэтому то мы и минусуем друг-друга :) Засим позвольте откланяться.

Comment: @AntonMenshov сожалею, резко высказался. "в том числе я не согласен с вашей оценкой вашего же ответа - он не нейтральный" вы про ответ на MSE?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica да, я про ответ Barmaley на мете, залинкованный в этом посте. Все ок.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, явного запрета на определённые аватары в правилах данного сообщества нет.

Если изображение на аватаре не нарушает общепринятых законодательных нормативов по публикации материалов в интернете, т.е. не содержит разжигание рассовой ненависти, призывов к насилию, порнографии и т.п., то его можно здесь использовать.

> Можно ли выражать политические взгляды через аватарку?

Вопрос более конкретный и явного запрета тоже вроде нет. Только встает вопрос -- а чем вызвано стремление выразить свои политические взгляды именно на данном ресурсе?

Цитата из [Ключевые ценности сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values):

> Любое взаимодействие на сайте начинается с взаимного уважения к коллегам, вне зависимости от обстоятельств, репутации, знаний или **чего–либо еще**.

Осмелюсь продолжить **чего–либо еще**: принадлежности к политическим или религиозным течениям (или приверженности таковых взглядов), пола, рассы или сексуальной ориентации.

Будет ли проявлено взаимное уважение к коллегам, размещая аватар с политическим "окрасом", политические взгляды которых с вашими не совпадают?

Исходя из вышеизложенного:

- Пожалуйста, используйте только нейтральные аватары и цитаты в профиле. При сомнении в нейтральности, пользуйтесь аватарами по умолчанию сгенерированными системой.
- Если заметите у кого-то не совсем "нейтральный" аватар, то проигнорируйте, не стоит сразу же устанавливать себе аватар на "противоположенный".