# Имена участников с лозунгами

Tags: обсуждение

Вы, наверно, знаете, что я имею в виду — имена типа *«Ваня У рыб право молчать!»*. Посмотрю в профиль такого участника, и в нем то же самое: *«У рыб право молчать!»*

Вне зависимости от того, если я с таким лозунгом соглашаюсь или нет, и если это соответствует правилам этого сайта или нет, мне это не нравится. По моему это злоупотребление нашего сайта, который предназначен для помощи одних другим в области программирования, а не для разделения общества.

Я бы хотел узнать мнения других участников по этому вопросу, включая модераторов.

Comment: Обсуждали [похожий вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9908/339283) в контексте аватаров. Насколько я понимаю, правила явно не оговаривают, можно ли использовать лозунги

Comment: Мне это не нравится. И дело даже не в том, что я что-то поддерживаю, а что-то нет. Просто это отвлекает. Если я вижу какой-то лозунг, я буквально вынужден прочитать его и задуматься. А захожу я не за этим — я просто хочу ответить на вопрос

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Но ведь когда все писали Reinstate Monica, их же не трогали - своеобразный прецедент с лозунгами. Давайте обсуждать, кто что думает. На данный момент мы не трогали лозунги обеих сторон, а также фрагмент песни Входа нет группы Ленинград в профиле пользователя (была тревога от англоязычных пользователей сети). Сохраняем нейтральность и стараемся не провоцировать лишнего шума и разборок.

Comment: @Qwertiy, по моему это тоже может искажать голосование — выдающийся ответ, но я очень сильно не соглашусь с лозунгом автора. Буду голосовать за его ответ? Или наоборот, ответ меня не устраивает, но лозунг автора очень сильно совпадает с моим убеждением. Я буду голосовать за, но мой голос будет на самом деле не за ответ, а за автора.

Comment: @MarianD, по-хорошему, надо голосовать, не смотря на автора сообщения. Более того, в интерфейсе имя пользователя показывается после стрелочек, приходится прокручивать (если ответ длинный).

Comment: @MarianD, ну так можно к чему угодно придраться. Может имя с именем твоего знакомого совпадает, а вы поругались?)) Голоса должны именно по качеству ответов даваться, а не имени, лозунгу или истории участника.

Comment: @MarianD, кстати, ещё в пользу того, чтобы не трогать лозунги - вполне могут быть нейтральные приписки типа "from Kiev", которые формально ничего не выражают, но всё равно очевидно связаны с ситуацией.

Comment: @mymedia, окей, я так буду голосовать, и вы тоже. И остальных 300 тысяч???

Comment: @Qwertiy, по-видимому, это более сложная проблематика, чем я думал. Спасибо вам за объяснение.

Comment: @Qwertiy Если про Kiev намек на меня, то я это из имени убрал. А про аватар разговора не было :)

Comment: @Harry, да, такую приписку я видел именно у тебя, тем не менее, такую ведь может написать кто угодно. Если начинать чистить, то грань между допустимым и нет провести сложно, поэтому я был за то, чтобы оставлялись всё. Ещё был вариант делить по принципу есть ли призыв (например, "stays with" - можно, а "stop" - нельзя), но не стали, по крайней мере пока.

Comment: Зарекаюсь поддаваться здесь на провокации и высказывать свою точку зрения.

Comment: @XelaNimed непопулярная точка зрения должна быть подана очень красиво и понятно, либо будет закономерно не одобрена к существованию. А еще должна быть идея, которая нравится большинству. Моя идея - сохранение жизнеспособности и осмысленности SO, а не просто призыв к порядку. Вы этот посыл не уловили (фактически всё остальное повторили как в моем ответе), за что и были справедливо оценены (не мной, я не успел).

Comment: @Qwertiy если "stop" нельзя, то хочу напомнить, что ещё месяца 3 назад я попросил модераторов поговорить с участником [Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218971/roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua) о его нике  или [MaxU - stop genocide of UA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu-stop-genocide-of-ua), но никто так этого и не сделал ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   И есть ещё вполне несколько таких ников (в приницпе по поиску этого слова видно будет участников)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не вижу оснований, почему необходимо говорить с этими участниками по поводу этих ников. Такой регуляции (по моему знанию правил SE) - просто нет.

Comment: @AntonMenshov то, что нет конкретно чётких правил на это указывающих - не значит, что это правильно. Это как "что не запрещено, то разрешено". Вы же понимаете, что это бредово, правда? .......А вообще, потому, что что всем этим лозунгам и тем более таким в целом не место на специализированных ресурсах. На политическом - да, на акциях протеста и пр. - да. На ресурсе **для программистов** - нет.

Comment: @AntonMenshov  И в целом, меня они оскорбляют. Лично я ни на кого не нападал, я не агрессивный, я никого не истребляю и не занимаюсь геноцидом. У меня на работе коллега с/из Украины. Прекрасно ладим (да  и почему это должно было стать поводом относится как-то не так?). А эти лозунги получается говорят, что все русские такие, все сволочи и гады. Меня вот это задевает.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский то, что вы эти "лозунги" так читаете - это лишь одна из интерпретаций. Исходя из моих критериев модерации, такие высказывания не направлены на конкретного человека (или даже группу лиц), а на конкретные действия страны\государственного образования.

Также я не вижу причин, почему на ресурсе для программистов в своем нике\профиле я не могу указать информацию, которую считаю важной. Такие правила МОГУТ быть установлены, но совсем не должны.

Comment: @AntonMenshov А если я считаю важным донести своё вероисповедание в виде поклонения гиганскому **ю? Да да, именно не писе или члену (это вполне разрешимое слово), а именно **ю? Вот для кого-то это будет неприемлемой информацией, хотя даже не оскорбляет никого, а для меня - важная, как для кого-то веганство, пастафарианство или женитьба на рисоварке (это реальная история)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не знаю как вы это сформулируете в вашем нике, давайте посмотрим на конкретный ник. Будет прецедент - будем (точнее сообщество\модераторы Ru.SO\SE в целом) смотреть. К этой ситуации я бы тоже подходил с позиции максимального ограничения цензуры и разрешения.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский также не стоит забывать, что намерения (в дополнение к характеристике самих действий) - это тоже важно. И намеренный троллинг с целью тестов границ правил - не есть хорошо.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я сказал, что среди модераторов было обсуждение такого варианта, но сейчас действуем не по нему, а следовательно необходимости с кем-то связываться не было.

Comment: Что-то мне вспомнилось, как какой-то судья, что ли, сказал, что определения порнографии нет, но когда он ее увидит, то сразу поймет, что это она...

Comment: Какое значение как опубликована информация в сообщении или в никнейме? Если она носит неприемлемый характер её нужно удалять. Я в принципе не понимаю для чего выпячивать флажки свои будь то шахматы или программирование. Будь моя воля я бы олимпийские игры сделал для всех без исключения без флагов это лишь способствовало бы объективности судей и болельщиков.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Считаю выражение личной/гражданской/политической позиции по вопросам не касающимся тематики сайта в никнеймах/профилях/аватарах и т.д. неуместной. Мне известны крупные сообщества, где это явно запрещено правилами, и где зачинщиков банят без предупреждения. Здесь не запрещено.

Не так уж много здесь этих "выражений позиции". Стоило бы задуматься, если данная тема превратила бы сайт в свалку таких инцидентов с устраиванием бардака на почве межнацрозни и прочих розней, риск определенно есть. А пока пусть будет, лично мне это не мешает использовать SO по назначению.

Думаю, что администрация и модераторы следят за происходящим и обращают внимание. Будет повод принять меры - примут, я полагаю.

Comment: Не знаю как голосовать за ответ)) до слов "А пусть пока будет..."  был "За", начиная с них - "против" ))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так не я же решаю, что будет, а что нет. Я сначала выразил мнение о явлении, а потом о том, а проблема ли это вообще.

Comment: Я понимаю, но ответ всё же должен содержать что-то такое однозначное, с чем можно было согласиться (солидарен) или наоброт, как и на основном сайте: помог или нет. ...... а вообще, если достаточное количество голосов будет (не могу сказать точную цифру), то на это, как раз, можно обратить внимание и в итоге повлиять. Такое уже было не раз.

Answer (score 15):

Есть такая негласная рекомендация, не говорить с незнакомыми людьми о религии и о политике. А все потому, что это все может как быть оскорбительно для других, так и провоцировать ненужные споры и различные виды неприязни.

Мы все здесь собрались, чтобы решать задачи программирования, собирать БД вопросов и ответов связанных с программированием, а значит выражение полит позиции не является целью сайта и это чисто самодеятельность.

При этом на ruSO политические дискуссии запрещены везде, кроме одной чат комнаты, потому вывешивание политических лозунгов в профили по сути только отталкивает людей, ведь человек, который видит лозунг, с которым не согласен, не может ответить ничем.

Также замечу, что модерация ников и аватаров уже присутствует. Я помню гонения на человека с аватаркой флага СССР (ссылку лень искать). Различные непотребности также банятся на раз, типа фашистских символик в никах или на аватарках. Потому не надо думать, что тут нет модерации, она есть, только не для всех.

Лично я считаю, что например, показывать флаг своей страны или гимн или что еще про свою страну в профиле - вполне допустимо, а вот высказывать политическую позицию - уже нет. И люди, которые выставляют свою политическую позицию в никах, попросту показывают своё наплевательское отношение к другим участникам сообщества.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139639/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167----).

Answer (score 9):

Ребят, я считаю, что мы все забыли с вами что такое ник (у нас это зовется `Отображаемое имя`). Цитата с [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA):

> Никне́йм (ник; англ. nickname /ˈnɪkneɪm/ — первоначально «кличка, прозвище», от древнеанглийского an eke name — «другое имя», перешедшее в одинаково звучащее «a nick name»), также сетевое имя — псевдоним, используемый пользователем в Интернете, обычно в местах общения (в блогах, форумах, чатах) как более короткая или новомодная альтернатива реальному имени. В частности, в онлайн-играх при регистрации или создании персонажа вместо имени необходимо ввести оригинальный ник. Никнейм характеризует представившегося и является многофункциональным средством добавления выразительности в высказывания.

Другими словами "Ник" - это, по сути, то, как человек хочет, чтобы к нему обращались. Это как в реальной жизни имя, только в интернете человек вправе сам придумать себе свой собственный "идентификатор". Теперь давайте зададим себе вопрос, какого отношения имеют эти все лозунги к идентификации человека? Это его титул, должность, компания может где работает, достижение, что?

Давайте вот разберем несколько ников:

- `Mark Kromer MSFT` - видим приписку `MSFT`, что говорит нам о том, что человек скорей всего из компании Microsoft. Сразу понимаем, что с нами разговаривает специалист.
- `Yakk - Adam Nevraumont` - видим ник, а также имя.
- `Pradeep AJ- Msft MVP` - нам видно достижение человека то, что у него награда MVP от Microsoft.

А теперь давайте посмотрим на такие ники:

- `Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA` - мы видим, что человека зовут Андрей, а дальше что? Как это воспринимать? Если это в нике, то наверно это его достижение, он наверно помог остановить агрессию, так? Думаю нет... Тогда почему это там, где должно быть то, как мы должны обратится к этому человеку?
- `Russia Must Remove Putin` - на удивление [модератор](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541136/russia-must-remove-putin), но да ладно... Как тут мы должны обращаться к человеку? Может `Russia`? Или может `Putin`? Как?

И тут мы понимаем, что ломается некое представление о человеке, мы не можем понять с кем именно общаемся, ибо мы просто видим "нечто", вместо "Вася". Видел новость (даже не одну), где родители дают детям разные уникальные имена, вот там было такое `БОЧ рВФ 260602`, и вот представьте реакцию других людей на такое имя, как они будут обращаться к этому ребенку? Некоторые наверно сократят до `Боч` (что тоже ужасно), некоторые придумают "кликуху" (которая может не понравиться человеку), ну а некоторые и вовсе начнут игнорировать этого ребенка без каких-либо веских на то причин. Вот с никами, как по мне, примерно тоже самое, не так выраженно наверно, но +- ситуация похожа. Тут в комментариях видел, что ник сравнивают с футболкой, как по мне, не совсем правильное сравнение, тут больше подойдет не футболка, а ваше имя, вот к вам на конференции будут все обращаться "Андрей против Русских", а тут уже сами понимаете, не каждый захочет такое произнести, не каждый такое воспримет. На SO мы ведь тоже через `@` обязаны писать постоянно это все, будто выговаривая ваше имя.

К этому всему, можно добавить то, что теряется удобство использования этого ресурса, вот не знаю как вы, а я лично пишу комментарии почти не трогая мышь, даже не смотрю на клавиатуру, многие ники я пишу сам, но некоторые, особенно с приписками, вынуждают меня нажать `@` и тянуться до мыши чтоб кликнуть на нужный ник. Конечно, это не столь критично, но все равно, для меня сайт в последнее время становится все менее удобней, чем он был раньше.

**Итог посыла:**
Мне кажется, тут не нужна "цензура", мы ведь все люди, имеем право на высказывание своих мыслей (в рамках приличия конечно), но здесь нужна "модерация". Простые как минимум два условия: Ник должен быть читаем (без китайских всяких символов и прочего), и ник должен быть "идентификатором" (как минимум, мы должны понимать с кем общаемся). Вот, собственно, и все, простое следование стандартам чтоль, которые предоставляет нам ресурс. Ну а все эти лозунги, для них ведь есть отличное место под названием "Обо мне", именно та "футболка", о которой говорили комментаторы, где каждый может написать то, что пожелает нужным, а при наведении на человека в любом вопросе, мы увидим его карточку с этим описанием, ну и что, этого разве мало? Скажете: "Не все увидят" - а вот тут я скажу следующее, если вы пишете такое лишь для того, чтоб задеть других, а не просто поддержать кого либо, или высказать свое мнение, то я считаю это троллингом, который неуместен на этом, вроде как серьезном ресурсе.

Comment: `если вы пишете такое лишь для того, чтоб задеть других` как будто есть какая то другая причина написания лозунгов в никах

Comment: `ник должен быть "идентификатором"` что делать, если я идентифицирую себя как послание от нации Х к нации Y?

Comment: имхо, судить надо просто. Пишешь только про себя, пиши хоть "Великий_и_могучий_борец_за_Х" - на здоровье, но если твой ник что то говорит не только о тебе, но и о ком-то еще "Остановите_Х_от_Y, X_нехорошие, Х_делают_Y" и тд - то этому не место в никах, хоть как себя идентифицируй.

Comment: @tym32167 `как будто есть какая то другая причина написания лозунгов в никах` - с *таким* подходом, вы вообще **ВСЁ** что пишется можете трактовать как причину задеть других? :-D

Comment: "тут не нужна "цензура"" --- на самом деле нужна. Т.к. кто может хочет называться "буй_с_горы" и ему норм, а вот для других не оч.

Comment: @Kromster с чего бы? Я вроде ясно выразился, что речь про лозунги в никах

Comment: `другая причина` - некоторые просто это ставят в виде "флешмоба", не понимая даже зачем. `идентифицирую себя как` - я считаю это бредом, троллингом. `на самом деле нужна` - я в ответе написал "в рамках приличия конечно". Тут речь была именно про такие политические лозунги, их запрещать, ну, бессмысленно. Только вот это не является "ником", и не имеет к нему вообще какого-либо отношения, а значит место ему в "Обо мне" (как на форумах, подпись), вот и весь посыл. А цензура - ну конечно мы все понимаем, что всякий мат, дичь, и прочее там неуместно.

Comment: @Kromster кто-то позволяет себе такие ники, я не позволяю себе из уважения к ресурсу и людям здесь, но хотел бы, и это задевает. Кто-то позволяет себе сорить на улице, я не позволяю себе, но было бы проще в некоторых ситуациях если бы позволял, наличие мусора меня задевает. Классическая психология, не читайте между строк.

Comment: если вас смущают длинные ники - можно писать только первые несколько букв, не меньше чем 3 буквы

Answer (score 5):

Считаю, что лозунги вполне могут быть приемлимы, если они соответствуют большинству УК РФ и других стран, (и соответствуют правилам StackOverflow) - не разжигают рознь, не унижают человеческое достоинство, и т.п. и т.д.

*P.S. А вы тоже заметили, что в вопросе нет ни слова про политику, а во всех ответах есть?*

Comment: Ну то есть вы видите, что политические лозунги людей задевают, но при этом вы ок их иметь, если они не противоречат законам стран?

Comment: @tym32167 Это достаточно умозрительный эксперимент .. но думаю что могу с вами согласиться, некоторые нейтральные политические лозунги было бы неприятно видеть. В целом, я скорее сторонник того, что роль личности на SO стоит немного уменьшить. Главное - вопросы и ответы, а не их автор. *Если что, я ваш ответ поправил, но не минусовал*

Comment: Да, я видел, что поправили, не понял только зачем, там ничего вроде не изменилось особо. Ну и минусите если хотите, я только приветствую, если люди высказывают свою позицию плюсами/минусами, а не полит лозунгами в профилях =)

Answer (score -1):

[Имена с лозунгами разрешены](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340087/383809) ([еще тут](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349167/2452869)):

> ...Yes, political statements are allowed in display names. Calling for them to not be allowed there is calling for any advertisement in a display name to not be allowed, which is simply not something we can enforce adequately, or really have any interested in enforcing.

Мой вольный перевод:

> Да, политические утверждения разрешены в никах. Призыв к их запрету - это, собственно, призыв к запрету любой рекламы в никах. Мы не заинтересованы в таком запрете по сути, а также это очень сложно технически.

Мое личное мнение: **НЕТ политической цензуре** в профилях и никах.

Comment: Цензура политическая есть везде, просто в одних местах цензурируют одно, в других другое. И SO - не исключение.

Comment: @aepot, если она и есть везде, то это не значит, что цензура это правильно и не надо с ней бороться

Comment: @avp не мне судить о правильности или неправильности цензур, но всё хорошо, когда в меру. Порядок против бардака, чего-то больше, чего-то меньше, но скатываться полностью в одну из сторон полностью определенно не стоит. С этой точки зрения я конечно за борьбу и поддерживаю автора ответа.

Comment: @avp, по вашему с сайта стоит удалить кнопки "закрыть" и "тревога"? Это же тоже элементы цензуры.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов речь в данном вопросе, в данном ответе и цепочке комментариев шла исключительно о цензуре политической.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, в принципе, убрать эти кнопки было бы неплохо. По крайней мере часть вопросов не закрывалась бы из-за некомпетентности и стадного инстинкта. (а дурь и грязь, на которую никто  внимания не обращает быстро уходит со страницы)

Answer (score -3):

Я могу легко выразить свое мнение, что поддерживаю `tym32167` в этом вопросе, но это может считаться отсутствием корректности(если выражение не уместное), потому что я уже нажал на галочку, тем самым высказав свое мнение. Это проблема личного характера... Но,   нельзя просто взять и сказать, что политические, или другие вредоносные  лозунги, не нарушают порядок в SO. Очевидно,  это ложь. Просто не уместные лозунги, никоим образом не нарушающий отношения или порядок, есть проблема  личная.
Я вообще думаю, что пора жестко наводить порядок по всему интернету. Но люди не хотят серьезно задуматься над тем, что если сегодня это их не задевает или порядок им не выгодно, то "завтра" двойным ударом обрушится на их детей и внуков.  Вопрос конечно спорный, потому что может возникнуть справедливый вопрос " что подразумевается под словом **порядок**?". Точно так же есть спорный вопрос с именами участников с лозунгами. Вредит ли это отношениям в (со)обществе или цели и назначения конкретного сайта(приложения)?.. В этом направлении должны серьезно работать все модераторы и выше, потому что все очень не однозначно. Очевидно только одно _ все, кто отвечает за порядок, должны нести серьезную ответственность.

Comment: "Надо наводить порядок" .. "что подразумевается под словом порядок?" - у вас это риторический вопрос или на него предполагается какой-то ответ в теле поста?

Comment: @Kromster,  еще хуже, когда люди не знают "что подразумевается под словом порядок?"....