Синонимизировать метки на тему [расширения]
Есть две метки для синонимизации:

extension - 70 вопросов (есть описание)
расширения - 84 вопроса

Главное -- расширения (на русском языке, больше вопросов).

Кстати, приписка в нике (в купе с флагом и гербом) выглядит весьма отвратно. Также см. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12128

@Kromster к сожалению руководство никак с этим ничего делать не собирается, поэтому смысла писать об этом учатсникам - тоже нет.... Я тоже против этого, но  всем остальным включая, к сожалению, владельцев - пофиг

@Kromster Почему отвратно? Вывешивание флага и герба определенной страны в профиле не нарушает никаких норм, и тема по ссылке к этому никакого отношения не имеет. Когда администрация поддерживала другую страну, вы не писали, что это "отвратно". Очередные двойные стандарты?

Кстати, в список можно внести [tag:addons]. Тоже по теме расширений.

@Kromster скажите тоже самое MaxU.

Ну, так синонимизировать-то будем или нет?
