Уместен ли оскорбительный никнейм?
Господа модераторы, а объясните это пожалуйста. Я допустим, считаю данный ник оскорбительным, а если прочитать наоборот (Михайловна Тварь), то это уже конкретное оскорбление, конкретного отчества человека. Допустим, если бы у моей матери, жены, дочери, да любого другого родственника было такое отчество, то для меня подобные ник будет оскорбительным. Я конечно понимаю, все мы "Твари божьи", но давайте на SO без этого.

Ну и раз такое дело, давайте проговорим и про старую тревогу. Вы считаете это уместным ником? Ребят, человек русскоговорящий, игрок в доту, скорей всего типичный школьник. Неужели вы не понимаете, что это "троль" ник? Тут либо "Еб.л доту", либо "Еб.н из доты", либо аналоги, придумывайте сами. Ок, можем загуглить, найдем замечательный канал, где есть такие видосы. Я конечно не утверждаю, что это один человек, но не суть, мы сейчас с свами обсуждаем конкретный ник, который я считаю неуместным на SO. Я могу этот ник принять на EnSO, ибо зарубежные слова для нас воспринимаются иначе. Есть вон даже разные песни, по типу "С добрым утром", а мы слышим "Хуеморган Хуета". Но давайте будем все же смотреть через призму русскоговорящих людей, ведь у нас RuSO, а русскоговорящий человек себе подобный ник вряд-ли просто так возьмет.

С таким подходом страшно представить, что будет дальше, ибо если такое "уместно", то значит смело можно брать всякие "Мразь", "Урод", и так далее. "Мразь Сидорова" а, как вам? Скажете "ну это уже прямое оскорбление". Почему тогда "Тварь Михайловна" нет? Хорошо, давайте пойдем в биологию, с кобелями и суками, типичные слова, подобное в учебниках пишут, а значит по логике модераторов SO будет уместно "Сука Федорова". Верно понимаю? Русский язык богатый, очень. Так может все же мы такое будет убирать с SO, а? Ну не место этому здесь, не место.

Любопытный случай произошел, который очень наглядно показывает то, что подобные ники неуместны на SO! Случай этот в комментариях, которые скорей всего подотрут, но ключевое от туда сохраню:

После чего на меня сильно обиделись, будто "Твари" человек воспринял на свой счет (предполагаю), когда как я лишь упомянул конкретный ник, который мы тут обсуждаем. Я конечно может что не так понял в этом "ночном перфомансе", но случай весьма наглядный и такое может произойти с любым.

Сука - это ещё японская фамилия, да и вообще слово такое есть, переводится как "ясный", "ясность". Мразь бы я не пропустил конечно. З.Ы. тревогу обрабатывал не я.

Тварь Михайловна и Мразь Сидорова — более, чем реальные имена. Это из разряда Гнида Андреевна и т. д. и т. п.. По поводу других ников (дотер) — да, это оскорбления (завуалированные и не очень)

Во, даже анекдот вспомнил

Господа, да я не спорю, что такое "реально" и такое "есть". Я сейчас говорю, что на ruSO такого быть не должно. Мы вроде как "сообщество профессионалов", а на деле, будто в цирке с клоунами. Да и уверен, что приведенный ник - это не реальная фамилия/имя человека.

Вам нужно делать скидку для людей за 40+. Ну, имя у них такое, что им делать с этим? Не думаю, что они себе будут ники придумывать...

@Chaos_Sower Еще раз повторю, я считаю это неуместным на SO. Да даже если это реальное имя, это не значит, что оно не оскорбляет других людей. Мы сидим в интернете, где паспорт менять ради ника не обязательно, вписать туда можно что угодно, хоть "Самолет", а это еще один повод такие ники не допускать.

@EvgeniyZ, да ерунда это. Вы бы лучше озаботились, почему отсюда теперь такой отток (вряд ли это такое количество сверхобидчивых на непотребщину)

@avp Без обид, честно, но с вами говорить про SO я вообще не хочу. Я уже давно понял то, что у нас с вами в корне противоположные взгляды. Для меня SO это "база вопросов" - для вас это "форум"; для меня неуместны базовые "домашки", которые гуглятся и решаются в 2 клика - вы против их удаления; для меня GPT ответы неуместны на SO - вы опять, против их удаления; и т.д... Сейчас к этому списку прибавляются еще и ники, где для меня это неуместно - для вас "ерунда".

Как по мне, всех подобных "нетакусиков" нужно добровольно-принудительно переименовывать в user1453575 и никак иначе. ЭТО НЕ НОРМАЛЬНО! ТС, я с вами полностью солидарен.

@EvgeniyZ, какие обиды? Я же сторонник свобод, поэтому приемлю, что человек может разделять любые взгляды. Вы уже зашли в Опрос для пользователей: как вернуть активность на ru.SO? и попытались помочь сайту стать лучше (привлекательней)?

@avp Прекращайте флудить несвязанными друг с другом темами. Я ведь не спрашиваю под тем постом "А почему ники такие допустимы?". Вы сейчас как человек с листовкой в торговом центре, который тычет каждому прохожему ее прям в нос. Нормальная такая у вас "свобода".

Вопрос коннечно довольно странный. Меня например такое бы не оскорбило. Если это была моя фамилия или даже отчество.

@чистов_n А если будет "Тварь чистов_n", ну или наоборот "чистов_n Тварь"?

@EvgeniyZ это уже обращение не по фамилии, а по нику, и это уже явное оскорбление конкретного человека.

@чистов_n А чем фамилия отличается от ника? И то и то носят люди. Или это "слишком общее"? Мы сейчас с вами ведь не говорим про упомянутые мною "Тварь Божья", где идет некая абстракция, там еще может быть и ок, я бы прошел мимо, и то, считаю такое неуместным на SO... Мы сейчас говорим про конкретный ник, в котором есть конкретное отчество, которое есть у кучи людей и это отчество идет с оскорбительным в данном контексте словом "Тварь". Так что, как по мне, "Тварь Михайловна" и "Тварь чистов_n" - это два одинаково оскорбительных ника.

@EvgeniyZ, как странно вы отреагировали на мое неравнодушие к судьбе ruSO (...)

@avp В данном вопросе мы не решаем судьбу SO, да и скажу честно, не нам ее решать. Данным вопросом я затронул конкретную ситуацию, с которой хочется разобраться и увидеть мнение модераторов, а также сообщества. Ну а вы просто перетягиваете внимание с моего вопроса на что-то другое, вот и все. Чего тут странного? Вот если у вас допустим будет проблема с SO, допустим, не работает отправка ответов, вы идете и пишете на мете про эту проблему, а к вам прибегают комментаторы  с "Ерунда это все, иди лучше реши судьбу SO!". Вот тоже самое делаете сейчас вы. Странно, что я вообще это должен объяснять.

на мой взгляд такое трудно контролировать. Тк, есть те, кто считают, что литературные слова это норма, даже, если они звучат менее приемлимо для привычной нормы общения, и есть те, кто говорят, что это некрасиво, давайте сделаем красиво и чисто, но это сугубо личное мнение, и голоса на данном вопросе подтверждают это, что не такое уж и обидное (Тварь Михайловна). Это узкий и щепетильный момент. этот ник я видела, двоякое чувство вызывает, явно его хозяин человек меньше 20ти лет. Мне больше раздражают политические ники тут  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12128/264178

а еще представим момент (понятно, что 3 процента из ста), что человека и правда Тварь  зовут...и он потом паспорт покажет модераторам и еще и прав окажется. Там не мат, там литературное слово...

@Dev18 "двоякое чувство вызывает" - как по мне, это существенный повод для удаления подобных ников. Это раздражающий фактор, который только отталкивает от SO, по крайней мере меня. Я не хочу видеть у себя на экране всяких "тварей". Если ник может задеть часть людей, то его не должно быть на SO. Как по мне, тут нет ничего сложного. "Тварь" - это оскорбление в русском языке, и чаще всего именно как оскорбление оно и используется. Это не нейтральный ник. Я даже больше скажу, этот ник противоречит "Би найс" принципам SO. По поводу "может быть" я уже сказал выше.

Если ник может задеть часть людей (а часть против такого тотального очищения) => в сообществе решает большинство, голосами на вопросе, если модератор принял непонравившееся вам решение...А тут сухие голоса все скажут... (важно помнить, что у каждой эпохи есть свои негласные правила, читая старые вопросы, и видя некоторые комментарии, мне порой не по себе, а ведь это принималось как норма)...возможно ваш вопрос поднимут лет через пять...если тут еще останутся люди ) //но минусы могут идти и от подачи вопроса - это играет роль, много лишнего...много эмоций...

@Dev18 Голоса на SO уже давно ничего не решают. Хоть тысяча голосов ЗА если будет, модератор может спокойно стоять на своем и не реагировать на это. Таковы реалии SO. Ну а голоса большинства - оставлю пожалуй тут....

двоякое чувство вызывает => потому что глядя на фото/вопрос, данного участника, я вижу, что этот юноша не хотел никого обидеть, (может даже он себя так называет) это видно мне лично невооруженным взглядом, а то, что мне это не нравится...ну не одна же на планете и на стековерфлоу я...поправьте ваш вопрос, оставив только ник и ссылку на него можно добавить, по-моему так больше будет концентрация на самом вопросе, а не на красках //и вы не правы, голоса решают и сообщество у нас  не дохлая рыба, и минусы поставили прочитав вопрос. Измените его, может больше пользы будет...

Вопрос очень плохо сформулирован и по форме скорее похож на [tag-meta: нытьё], но по сути - согласен, +1.

@Kromster Есть идеи по улучшению, дерзайте. Хоть полностью перепишите. Я не вижу ни единого "нытья" в вопросе, четко структурированный текст, где все разложил вроде как по полочкам, с конкретными примерами и моими мыслями по этому поводу. Чего не так, я хз. Или нужно было как сказали вон выше, просто ник и "Уместен"? Тут уж извините, потеряется вся суть. Но допустим, ок, не нравится, вперед, я не против.

@aepot, а Альберт - это модераторы, или участник сам?

@Dev18 не понял вопроса

Значит он сам... Тварь Михайловна теперь Альберт))) что ещё раз доказывает, что простое общение может решить вопрос. Я поделилась ссылкой под его вопросом и теперь он больше не Тварь, а Альберт... ❤️

@Dev18 "что ещё раз доказывает, что простое общение может решить вопрос" - вопрос не к "Твари", а к модераторам, почему такое допустимо. Также интересна была реакция и мнение сообщества. Так что, нет, простым "общением" подобное не решить. Кстати любопытный момент, вот я упомянул его в этом комментарии, это ведь, по сути, оскорбление, на которое любой другой участник может кинуть тревогу и в теории, модераторы должны наказать. Вот вам и еще один повод не допускать подобные ники. P.S. Модераторы не умеют менять ники, они их только сбрасывают до idЦифры.

При регистрации можно было бы внедрить проверку на ник... За ваш ник проголосовали против 5 участников...таким образом, участник понимает, что на это обращают внимание и меняет, либо зная все равно оставляет. Но внедрять никто ничего не будет, так как нас забросили ... И да, Евгений, я тут отвечаю под темой, не вам лично, не обязательно на все реагировать и флудить

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct вот держите, чтоб не искать

ТС, всецело поддерживаю вашу позицию, поэтому считаю важным высказаться: на мой пусть и субъективный взгляд, подобные ситуации требуют строгого модерирования. Никнеймы, содержащие оскорбительные, провокационные, политические слова\высказывания и т.д…, а в данном случае «Тварь Михайловна», совершенно неуместны и абсолютно не приемлемы на платформе профессионалов, если, конечно, мы таковой считаем ruSO.
SO в целом ориентировано на сообщество людей, наша цель — обмен знаний, взаимопомощь. Но когда среди никнеймов появляются всякие высеры, уж простите — это разрушает всю профессиональную атмосферу сообщества. В конце концов, каждое слово имеет свою смысловую нагрузку, а в русском языке слово "тварь" - воспринимается как оскорбление (по большей части). Даже если для автора это слово несет иное значение, то для меня оно все же негативное, что в свою очередь кидает тень на всё сообщество и площадку в частности.
Под самим постом уже успели вспомнить о принципе "Be Nice". Давайте его освежим? Правило "Be Nice" (Будь добр\вежлив) — это фундаментальный принцип любого здорового сообщества, который подразумевает не только уважительное отношение в комментариях и вопросах, но и в выборе никнеймов. Присутствие оскорбительных слов, даже если это отчасти шутка или самоирония, идет вразрез с этим принципом, и любые оправдания этому - БРЕД. Или здравый смысл уже покинул это место?!
Моё виденье такого, что использование подобных ников и отсутствие на это реакции модераторов приведёт к тому, что это станет нормой, а атмосфера сообщества, которая и так еле держится на плову – в край деградирует. Отсутствие реакции несомненно приведёт к увеличению количества участников, использующих троллинговые, провокационные, оскорбительные, политические и т.д. имена, а SO из профессиональной платформы превратится в нечто среднее между форумом и чатиком, что отпугнет часть активных участников (меня так точно).
Я за установку ЧЕТКИХ правил для всех! Важно, просто критически необходимо чтобы на платформе существовали правила и границы, касающиеся никнеймов. Сейчас же выходит, что правил нет и можно использовать слова\фразы оскорбительного характера и реакции на это не будет. Может мне никнейм сменить на Х_У_Й? Ничего плохого я конечно же не подразумеваю, просто это 3 моих любимых буквы из русского алфавита. Или вы против русского алфавита? (поясните пожалуйста этот момент)
Банальная проверка никнеймов на этапе регистрации могла бы послужить отличным началом для улучшения ситуации. Это бы исключило прямые оскорбления, сомнительные слова и фразы, что освободило бы модераторов от лишней работы и улучшило бы обстановку в целом. Разумеется, и сами модераторы должны участвовать в модерации ников и всех чей ник «Х_у__ло Ивановна» превращать в user100500.
К тому же молчаливое одобрение или закрытие глаз на никнеймы со спорными словами или троллинговым подтекстом — прямое приглашение для пользователей, не заинтересованных в содержательном участии. Бонусом -  это всё подогревает споры и раздувает конфликты среди равнодушных и неравнодушных как я и ТС. В итоге такие ситуации на перспективу вредят всему сообществу, ведь сюда заходят за решением вопросов и обсуждением профессиональных тем, а не вот это вот всё…
Моё виденье профессионального сообщество — это в первую очередь место для работы, объединения, учёбы, взаимопомощи, а не для троллинга или самовыражения через провокационные ники. Мы здесь для того, чтобы делиться опытом и решать задачи, и ради этого вполне стоит установить ограничения на подобные спорные ситуации. В конце концов, ограничения на ники помогут сохранить фокус сообщества на обмене знаниями и уважительном общении, а если вы с этим не согласны, то видно нам с вами не по пути и лично я всяким тварям помогать не буду и хоть заминусите меня всем стадом, но я подобного не приемлю и поддерживаю ТС всем сердцем!
P.S. Дорогие твари ("сотворённые", в библейском смысле) божьи, я искренне вас не понимаю. Как можно отстаивать права на сомнительное самовыражения в никнеймах и при этом в соседней теме на серьёзных щас обсуждать как спасти ruSO? У вас в голове ничего не ёкает? Казалось бы очевидное - очевидно, и обсуждать тут нечего, но нет.. цирк, просто цирк.

Мне не совсем понятно, почему слово "тварь" считает абсолютно неприемлемым. Изначально тварь это значит "сотворенное", в библейском смысле, то есть это лишь высокий синоним к слову "существо". Это слово оскорбительно лишь в определенном контексте. Если что-то и фильтровать в никах, то вряд ли только на основании того, что кому-то оно показалось оскорбительным.

@MSDN.WhiteKnight Давайте еще вспомним азь, язь и первый алфавит. В современном русском языке слово «тварь» уже давно утратило свой библейский оттенок, став нарицательным оскорблением. В повседневном\бытовом разговоре - это преимущественно используется в негативном контексте и воспринимается как уничижительное\оскорбительное. Да и на любой нормальной площадке вы такой ник не зарегистрируете и даже не создадите, его тупо не пропустят на уровне системы.

@MSDN.WhiteKnight Получается, что если вы подойдете к случайному человеку и спросите "тварь ли он?" то человек к вам не проявит агрессии, я правильно понимаю? Я свой вопрос дополнил про вчерашний случай, где я, в своем комментарии, написал "Вопрос не к "Твари", а к модераторам и сообществу", что, вроде как, человек принял на свой счет, из-за чего начался конфликт, хотя я просто упомянул обсуждаемый ник... Это опасное слово, даже если имеет безопасное значение.

"провокационные, политические" - ну лол, у кучи участников такие ники ещё со времён "Reinstate Monica", а с 2022 года так ваще

@andreymal так ваще для user есть куча свободных цифр.

Бинайс это, конечно, хорошо, а провакационные ники плохо. Но, все хорошо в меру. И вот когда толпа неумеренных активистов навязывает свои взгляды, то ruSO загнивает

@avp вашу позицию я уже понял. Что бы вернуть популярность ruSO надо разрешить любые треш никнеймы, не модерировать комментарии, разрешить любую даже самую тупую копипасту(привет гпт) в ответы/вопросы, не закрывать дубликаты и превратить ruSO в помойку, и вот тогда заживём. Генерация треша подымить ресурс в поисковой выдаче и народ подтянется и будут все твари божьи счастливы. Ванлав.

@Amgarak, вы уверены, что железная дисциплина способна привлечь нетривиальных людей? До сих пор я наблюдал как раз обратное.

Поражает прям логика людей. Соблюдение порядочности и уважение места в котором находишься - это строгая дисциплина. Концлагерь прям! Ходим строем и по расписанию, ага... Автор ответа, спасибо, что ты есть! Я уж думал все, этот мир не спасти и я один вижу в этом недопустимые слова. Казалось бы, очевидные вещи, но нет...

@avp не знаю чего вы там свидетель, но я не однократно наблюдал простую истину: анархия убивает любое сообщество.

@Amgarak, видимо  в реальной жизни мы крутимся в разных местах

@avp и слава богу.

@andreymal И это, кстати, плохо. Не, локальные события ок, еще могу понять, ибо это иногда бывает единственным способом достучаться до компании, некий "флешмоб" получается. Но когда уже идет "Стоп вар"... Уж извините, но это политика, которая может задеть конкретный пласт населения и может быть оскорбительной. Очень жаль, что RuSO это допустило. Правда смотря как сейчас на этот вопрос реагируют, не удивлен... Мерзко это, увы.

"Банальная проверка никнеймов на этапе регистрации могла бы послужить отличным началом для улучшения ситуации. Это бы исключило прямые оскорбления, сомнительные слова и фразы, что освободило бы модераторов от лишней работы и улучшило бы обстановку в целом." — 10/10 правда. Это и ДОЛЖНО быть внедрено для этого сайта. Но боюсь, что, видя текущую ситуацию, этот вопрос надо поднимать на enSO

Как по-мне без автопроверки ника на этапе регистрации (публикации вопроса/ответа) просить модераторов "чистить" ники бесполезно. Причины этого можно обсуждать долго, но объективно — таких ников будет очень много и искать их вручную так себе затея. Автопроверка ников может исправить проблему, а вот уже после (предпологаемого) внедрения такой проверки, модератерам будет проще сконцентрироваться на тех, кто осознанно ставит себе неприемлемый ник (пример в абзаце 5). Для таких людей и наказание можно применить более жёсткое (от ручного переименовывания в user... до краткосрочного бана).

Но пока такой проверки нет, не стоит наказывать провинившихся одинаково без оценки степени тяжести их проступка. В тексте АВ (автора вопроса) есть несколько ситуаций. Следует ли наказывать людей за такое — да. Одинаково ли — не думаю. 1) Ть Михайловна — не думаю, что пользователь поставил себе такой ник из злостных побуждений (ситуация 50/50). Вот может человека и правда так зовут, и она не ставила себе целью оскорбить кого-то. Тут надо бы сначала предупредить (попросить сменить ник), а при игноре выписать краткосрочный банан. 2) E*s Dota —  чистая провокация налицо, бан на подольше.

@Chaos_Sower не нужно специально выискивать плохие ники, достаточно реагировать на тревоги и добровольно принудительно превращать в user100500. Первый раз без санкций, второй и последующий раз с баном вплоть до перманентного.

Я понимаю, почему некоторые ники могут казаться неуместными, и поддерживаю стремление сделать платформу более дружелюбной для всех участников. Но если кто-то действительно заботится о "чистоте" и корректности никнеймов, логично, что это стремление должно распространяться и на собственное общение. Важно, чтобы тон дискуссий на мете оставался конструктивным и вежливым.
Задавать вопросы на мете — это нормально и приветствуется, но крайне важно делать это с уважением, чтобы диалог оставался конструктивным и не превращался в конфронтацию или, как в вашем случае, в стендап-манифест с ненужными ссылками/песнями и резкими личными оценками. Напоминаю, что соблюдение норм общения делает платформу комфортной для всех участников. Критика и обсуждения всегда будут более эффективными, если все поддерживают уважительный и объективный тон.
Так что, прежде чем говорить о необходимости "чистоты" никнеймов, разумно начать с себя и собственного общения и поведения. Соблюдая этот принцип, мы сможем поддерживать профессиональную и дружелюбную атмосферу, где каждый участник будет чувствовать себя комфортно.

Раз комментарий удалили, который касался  первой части, хорошо, перепишу под то, что касается оставшейся части: Это не ответ на поставленный вопрос! Тут вообще практически нету ничего про ники. Тут есть про "задавать вопросы на мете хорошо" и "следуй нормам поведения". То есть, это ответ личного характера, который нацелен исключительно на меня, а не решение или какого либо мнения по конкретной проблеме. Это тоже самое, если ответить на вопрос "2+2=?" примерно так: "Математика это хорошо, но и не забывайте кушать, ведь так вы более эффективно решите задачу!". И да, жду "пруфов".

Ты вопрос свой переделай, там мой комментарий и ложная информация. Какие пруфы тебе нужны, ты не помнишь, что ты писал вчера? Я не собираюсь пачкать платформу, могу распечатать по почте тебе отправить, если так с памятью сложно, что не помнишь, что ты писал

Как я и думал. Ответ написала лишь с целью дальнейшего выяснения отношений. Ни слова про проблему и что либо, о чем я подметил в комментарии. Ок, Ложная.... где? Я не утверждал, что ты из-за этого мне рот затыкать стала, лишь предположил. И удалять то, что висит до сих пор в комментариях? Ну, это странно. Или удалить тот кусок, где ты начинаешь на меня наезжать? Ок, удалю, без проблем. "ты не помнишь" - Упрощу задачу. Тыкни носом, с какого вдруг перепуга ты начала наезжать на меня и затыкать мне рот? Даже еще сильней облегчу - коммент с красным флагом.

... вот именно, что вопрос про 2+2, всем ясно, что такое не место тут, и все поддержат, вопрос только где грань провести и решить "список" запрещённых никнеймов, но подача отвратительная, поэтому и стоят минусы. Там не пишется как 2+2 решить, а пишется, как я мел держу смотрите... А ещё писать 2 могу... Если говорить на вашем сленге

Просто, "рука лицо"... Всем вдруг подача зашла, люди вон пишут ответы, дают свою реакцию, а для тебя вдруг "отвратительная подача". Я помню ты мне советовала все удалить и написать просто "Тварь уместный ник?", вот по твой логике такой вопрос должен быть, без какого либо объяснения проблемы, без примеров, без моего мнения, без всего. Ну что за бред, а?

"всем ясно" - а вот тут ты кстати ошибаешься, очень сильно. Почитай комментарии под вопросом, ответом, поймешь, что для людей "Тварь" это нормальное слово, уместно, и в нем нет ничего такого. Сообщество даже ответ заминусовало, хочешь сказать тоже из-за "отвратительной подачи"? Прошу, очнись, ибо ты летаешь в облаках, ожидая радужный и чудесный мир, когда на самом деле он не такой. Короче, жду хоть каких либо объяснений про наезды (кстати, они были даже до флага, первым комментарием после моей реакции), если докажешь, что я виноват, оскорбил, извинюсь. Нет, жду тогда их от тебя.

Я все еще жду "пруфов" или извинений. А по поводу комментария от "Дима К.", советую задуматься, ибо это действительно так, флудишь тут всегда только ты, даже этот ответ является флудом, а не обсуждение поставленного вопроса. Ну а своим флудом ты лишь задеваешь других.

Смотрю удалали мой правдивый комментарий. Нажаловалась, значит.  Правда глаза колит. Не удивительно.

Притча о коллективном безумии
В одном сообществе, что изначально славилось высоким духом взаимопомощи и уважения, жил мудрый участник. Однажды он предсказал, что придёт день, когда поток новых пользователей хлынет в сообщество с именами, далекими от вежливости и осмысленности, именами-насмешками, именами-оскорблениями, которые как мутная вода затопят всё сообщество. Они превратят общение в насмешку, сотрут грань между шуткой и оскорблением. И тогда место, где раньше царил порядок и уважение, превратится в хаос и бестактность, провозглашая беспринципность как принцип.
Мудрец пытался предупредить людей: «Если не воспримем это всерьёз, сообщество утратит свой смысл, и мы перестанем различать профессиональное общение от пустой ругани и троллинга». И хотя некоторые поддержали его, другие только посмеялись, заявив, что каждый вправе выбирать себе имя по вкусу, что свобода самовыражения важнее, чем чьи-то субъективные переживания.
Долго мудрец избегал общения с теми, чьи ники казались ему вопиющими, чтобы его собственный разум не поддался искушению забыть про важные ценности и цели сообщества. Он сторонился тех, чьи имена обесценивали смысл общения, а сам сосредоточился на помощи тем, кто искал настоящие знания и поддерживал дух сообщества.
Но день за днём в сообщество приходило всё больше людей с именами, которые разрушали даже намёк на профессионализм. Всё чаще обсуждения превращались в грубые шутки и личные выпады. Куда ни взгляни — везде мелькали уничижительные прозвища, и всё что казалось раньше значимым, теряло какой-либо смысл.
Когда мудрец наконец решился обратится к сообществу с просьбой вернуть порядок и уважение, его встретили смехом и насмешками. «Ты чудак!» — говорили ему. «Ты живёшь по старым правилам, разве ты не видишь, что теперь у нас свобода?»
И вот, оставшись в одиночестве среди тех, кто уже давно перестал помнить о профессионализме, мудрец ощутил, как на него самого смотрят, как на чужака. Толпа уже не стремилась к знаниям, не поддерживала порядочного общения. Сообществом стало править ирония, троллинг, а главное — бестактность, возведённая в Абсолют. Атмосфера стала анархичной, подчинённой не законам разума, а прихотям понятий. Наставления и мудрые слова стали восприниматься как атака на «свободу», как странность.
Не выдержав одиночества, мудрец отринул свои старые идеалы и принципы, приняв новые «нормы» морали. И в тот же миг он лишился разума и здравого смысла, его ум покинула последняя умная мысль, а вместе с тем — и тоска по утраченному порядку. Толпа же безумцев, заметив, что он изменился, одобрительно поставила плюсов и торжественно провозгласила: «Теперь он один из нас!».
P.S. Где прежде процветали знания и взаимоуважение, теперь царит безликая анархия.


Очень поэтично, спасибо. 2) Вы пишите так, словно прощаетесь, не надо


Мамааа-анархия!

Папааа-стакан портвейна!

О дивный новый мир, стерильный, утопийный и грустный.
