Какие ники неприемлемы на Stack Overflow?
В качестве небольшой акции предлагаю идею «чистки» отображаемых имён (ников). Если вы столкнулись с никнеймами, которые по объективным причинам могут восприниматься как неблагоприятные, оскорбительные и неподходящие для данного сайта, то делитесь ими в таблице, находящейся в ответе под данным вопросом — администрация примет решение: менять такой никнейм пользователя на более подходящий или оставить всё как есть.
По возможности оставляйте ссылку на этот пост под любым вопросом/ответом таких пользователей — так вы сможете связаться с самими участниками с целью урегулирования данного вопроса в более кратчайшие сроки без привлечения модераторов.
Вы также можете, как обычно, отправить информацию модераторам для проверки оскорбительных никнеймов. Однако занося оскорбительные никнеймы в таблицу, вы показываете другим участникам, какие ники неприемлемы на данном сайте.
Таблица собранных оскорбительных ников находится в общим посте-ответе. Эта таблица включает в себя: сам никнейм, ссылку на профиль пользователя, и количество голосов различных участников, которые согласны или не согласны с тем, что приведённый никнейм является оскорбительным/недопустимым.
Участники могут голосовать, корректируя пост (меняя число в таблице), добавляя - 1 или + 1 к имеющемуся числу.
Такой формат позволит участникам сообщества корректировать оценку никнеймов, добавляя или уменьшая баллы, что создаёт динамический и прозрачный процесс.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Я понимаю, что забота о сообществе важна, но я беспокоюсь, что инициатива о "чистке ников" может привести к нежелательным последствиям, таким как создание атмосферы вахтерства в сообществе, в которой участники могут чувствовать себя под давлением и опасаться за свой выбор никнейма.
Если участники сообщества станут стражами "приемлемости", это может вызвать недовольство и враждебность, в крайнем проявлении - кибербуллинг.
Никнеймы могут восприниматься по-разному, и то, что одному участнику может показаться оскорбительным, другому — совершенно приемлемым. Это создает риск создания конфликтов внутри сообщества и потенциального злоупотребления системой голосования.
Динамика сообщества может измениться, если участники начнут чувствовать себя незащищенными из-за возможности быть "оцененными" другими. Вместо того чтобы поддерживать позитивное взаимодействие, такая практика может создать атмосферу страха и недоверия.

простите, вы заставили меня по-другому посмотреть на ваш ник-нейм‍️раньше не замечала, как теперь развидеть...

@Dev18 Ничего такого я вроде не делал. извините. Что вы имеете в виду?

Спасибо за ответ! Согласна, что важно избегать осуждения. Голосование задумывалось, чтобы отражать мнение сообщества: если ник получает много "+" или "-", это показывает общее восприятие. Цель — поддержка, а не критика. Возможно, стоит доработать механизм, чтобы снизить возможные негативные эффекты?

@Dev18, Призыв участников голосовать за никнеймы и создаёт возможность осуждения и давления, даже если это не является целью. У нас есть модераторы и система тревог для решения таких вопросов, и это более безопасный и эффективный способ. Кроме того, демократические методы здесь не работают: мнением сообщества легко манипулировать, и не все участники представлены на мете. Лучше сосредоточиться на поддержании позитивной атмосферы, чем на оценивании других.

Я вас слышу, но как показал данный пост https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/14413/264178 => не сработала система тревоги, и есть мнение, что одному неприлично, другому отлично. Еще раз благодарю за ответ и отведенное время на его написание - ваше мнение ценно, далее участники продолжат реакцией на ваш ответ, ведь мы сообщество , я сказала свою часть♥️ //ставьте минус/плюс на сам пост, выражая вашу реакцию✅

"Никнеймы могут восприниматься по-разному, и то, что одному участнику может показаться оскорбительным, другому — совершенно приемлемым". Посмотрите на переименованные ники (до их переименовывания) — если вы хотите предоставить такую свободу, то это уже, извините, клиника

@Chaos_Sower, моя мысль не о том, что никнеймы должны быть полностью свободными от модерации. Напротив, вопрос в том, что оценка никнеймов через голосование несет риск субъективности и давления на участников. Объективную проверку лучше доверить модераторам и системе тревог, чтобы избежать конфликтов и сохранить позитивную атмосферу в сообществе.

Оставлю это под вашим ответом, чтобы не было дискуссии под вопросом. Вот: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14413 — мне нравится ответ пользователя @Amgarak (особенно часть про валидацию имён на этапе регистрации)

@Uranus, не думаю, что гонения на ники окажет какое-либо влияние на атмосферу сайта (большинство  не заметит, а те кто и заметит ничего в своем отношении из-за этого не изменят)

@avp, точно подмечено! Эта акция вряд ли повлияет на участников или их понимание того, какие ники приемлемы на Stack Overflow. Поэтому вместо того, чтобы тратить массу энергии на юзабилити голосовалки, которой пользуются 6 человек, усилия лучше направить на создание стабильных правил или автоматических проверок при регистрации

@Uranus, да, лучше бы напрвили свою энергию на то, чтобы закрывалиь-удалялись только действительно плохие вопросы и поняли, что «Лучше оправдать десять виновных, чем осудить одного невиновного», а также перестали вообще использовать причины "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ" и "вопрос слишком общий"


Данный ответ открыт для обновлений и внесения изменений и дополнений другими пользователями (в пределах нормы).
Пожалуйста, перед внесением изменений прочтите внимательно каждый пункт руководства.
К сожалению, на текущий момент у нас нет возможности автоматизировать процесс голосования и обновления статусов отображаемых имён. Мы предпринимаем меры по автоматизации данного поста и находимся в поиске решения.

Голосование в таблице никнеймов работает по тому же принципу, что и на сайтах Stack, а именно:

Если рейтинг голосов 1 и вы ставите минус, то рейтинг становится 0.
Если рейтинг 0 и вы ставите минус, то рейтинг становится -1.

Схема голосования:
1 → 0 → -1
Аналогично для голосования «за»:
-1 → 0 → 1

Не забывайте: если вы меняете свой голос на противоположный, то происходят два действия!
Представим такой рейтинг:
-1 (ваш голос «против») → 0 (передумали и убрали голос: рейтинг изменился) → 1 (поменяли голос на «за»: рейтинг изменился ещё раз)
Или такой:
1 (ваш голос «за») → 0 (передумали и убрали голос: рейтинг изменился) → -1 (поменяли голос на «против»: рейтинг изменился ещё раз)
Или такой:
0 (текущий рейтинг) → -1 (ваш голос «против») → 0 (передумали и убрали голос: рейтинг изменился) → 1 (поменяли голос на «за»: рейтинг изменился ещё раз)

Для голосующих — для вас таблица 1:

Прибавьте 1 напротив ника в колонке 3, если вы против него.
Не трогайте число в колонке 3 напротив ника, если вы относитесь к нему нейтрально.
Убавьте один напротив ника в третьей колонке, если вы считаете его приемлемым.

Пожалуйста, соблюдайте честность процедуры голосования — голосуйте за один ник единожды (даже если он вам ОЧЕНЬ не нравится). Вы можете проголосовать по каждому нику.
Вы можете изменить свой голос по нику, если передумали.
Пожалуйста, голосуйте только в таблице 1! Не голосуйте в таблицах 2 и 3 — голосование в них "заморожено" в целях соблюдения объективности.

Для редакторов (и/или модераторов ♦) — для вас таблицы 1, 2 и 3:
⚠️ Не изменяйте форматирование таблиц!
Не забывайте поддерживать актуальность таблицы! Не удаляйте пользователей, ники которых были переименованы. Вместо этого перенесите их без ссылки на профиль из таблицы 1 либо в таблицу 2 (если в колонке 4 таблицы 1 стоит статус ПЕРЕИМЕНОВАН), либо в таблицу 3 (если в колонке 4 таблицы 1 стоит статус ОТКЛОНЕНО).
Добавляйте ники пользователей, которые вы считаете неприемлемыми, в конец таблицы 1. Не забывайте, что если вы добавляете ник и считаете его недопустимым, то вам следует поставить ему изначальный рейтинг 1 при добавлении.
Если вы не уверены насчёт уместности никнейма, но решили предоставить возможность сообществу решить, приемлем он или нет, то занесите его в таблицу с изначальным рейтингом 0.
При добавлении ника укажите не краткую, а полную ссылку на профиль — так вы позволите другим редакторам занести информацию о неприемлемом нике, если он был переименован.

 Коллектив редакторов будет признателен модераторам ♦, если они будут переносить пользователей из таблиц сами.
Если же модератор ♦ хочет выполнить работу-минимум, то просьба указать в таблице 1 в колонке 4 статус рассмотрения заявки:

НА РАССМОТРЕНИИ
ПЕРЕИМЕНОВАН
ОТКЛОНЕНО




Таблица 1 "Неприемлемые ники" (для голосующих и модераторов ♦)

 

window.onload = function()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        var firstColumn = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        var secondColumn = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

        if (firstColumn && secondColumn)
        {
            firstColumn.classList.add("spoiler");
            secondColumn.classList.add("spoiler");

            firstColumn.onclick = function()
            {
                this.classList.toggle("show");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
            };
        }
    }
};
caption
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

table
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: Auto;
    margin-right: Auto;
}

th
{
    color: Black;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

td
{
    color: rgb(60, 65, 70);
}

tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

table, tr, th, td
{
    text-align: Center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: Gray;
    border-collapse: Collapse;
}

.spoiler
{
    color: Black;
    background-color: Black;
}

.spoiler:hover, .spoiler.show
{
    color: rgb(60, 65, 70);
    background-color: White;
}

#myTable a
{
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#myTable a:hover
{
    color: Red;
}
<table id="myTable">
    <caption>Таблица неприемлемых ников</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Никнейм</th>
        <th>Ссылка на профиль (нажмите ПКМ)</th>
        <th>Голос "Я против такого тут"</th>
        <th>Статус рассмотрения заявки</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Хам</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/567210" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>-2</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Индюк</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/390965" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>-3</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Пуп земли</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/570968" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>-1</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Почта Гандураса</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/550396" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Психушка</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/610181" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>-1</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Грязный Аркадий</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/447618" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>трухля пухля</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/643197" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>-1</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
        <td>рора</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/642385" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Попка Младенца</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/640356" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Amoral 666</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/640223" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>-3</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Какая-то собака</td>
        <td><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/511344" target="_blank">Смотреть профиль</a></td>
        <td>-4</td>
        <td>—</td>
    </tr>
</table>





Таблица 2 "Переименованные ники" (для редакторов)

 

window.onload = function()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        var firstColumn = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

        if (firstColumn)
        {
            firstColumn.classList.add("spoiler");

            firstColumn.onclick = function()
            {
                this.classList.toggle("show");
            };
        }
    }
};
caption
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

table
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: Auto;
    margin-right: Auto;
}

th
{
    color: Black;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

td
{
    color: rgb(60, 65, 70);
}

tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

table, tr, th, td
{
    text-align: Center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: Gray;
    border-collapse: Collapse;
}

.spoiler
{
    color: Black;
    background-color: Black;
}

.spoiler:hover, .spoiler.show
{
    color: rgb(60, 65, 70);
    background-color: White;
}
<table id="myTable">
    <caption>Таблица переименованных ников</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Никнейм</th>
        <th>Голос "Я против такого тут"<br>(голосование "заморожено")</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Дон Гандон</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>я Пидорас</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Бесплатное гей секс п0рн0</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Инклудни мою жопу</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>порнушечка гавнюшечка</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>не даун</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Бля Явахуе</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Баран</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Урод Уродский</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Тупица</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>svo hohlЫ pidorЫ</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pizda Roads</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Гнида</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>я какашка</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>NicKy 1982 Какашка</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Антоша Пиздюк</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Какой-то идиот</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>робот идиот</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
        <td>TwitchClipsRU Сукало</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Жопер</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>вилка в жопе</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Дора Дура</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>kykyepta</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kакашка Какашнута</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>





Таблица 3 "Приемлемые ники" (для редакторов)


caption
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

table
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: Auto;
    margin-right: Auto;
}

th
{
    color: Black;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

td
{
    color: rgb(60, 65, 70);
}

tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

table, tr, th, td
{
    text-align: Center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: Gray;
    border-collapse: Collapse;
}
<table id="myTable">
    <caption>Таблица приемлемых ников</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Никнейм</th>
        <th>Голос "Я против такого тут"<br>(голосование "заморожено")</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[Пример никнейма]</td>
        <td>[Рейтинг]</td>
    </tr>
</table>




Отренеймил часть.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Переименовал ещё пачку. Я думаю, переименованных можно просто удалить из таблицы, незачем им здесь никами светить. Если что, "голоса" я пока не учитываю при принятии решения, а обрабатываю то, что сам считаю неприемлемым и требующим немедленной реакции. К тому же провалидировать голоса - достаточно трудоёмкая задача, требующая изучения всей истории редактирования ответа.

На свежую голову сбросил ники ещё ряду кандидатов, некотоым с натяжкой. Остальные мне не кажутся достойными вмешательства модератора. Если вам так больно удалять плохие ники из таблицы, напишите под таблицей, что если кому интересно, пусть смотрят историю редактирования.

Очередной самокритичный персонаж, обнаружен в процессе поиска дубликатов, связанных с JavaFX.


Бессмысленно чистить такие "умершие" учетные записи, особенно
созданные кучу лет назад. Вот они уж точно не мешают, о них не знают,
их по сути не существует. Появятся, напишут, будет висеть в списке
активных вопросов, тогда да, ну а сейчас у всех этих записей
"Затронуто: 0". Подобными действиями мы просто нагрузим модерацию
бессмысленной работой. Не, если у них есть конечно время и силы,
вперед, но это бесполезно... Я вообще против изменения чего либо
старого, особенно редактирования старых вопросов/ответов
незначительными правками, могу понять только каноничные вопросы и
правку меток, все.
©EvgeniyZ

Согласен, что редактировать ники мёртвых аккаунтов бессмысленно, ведь их мало кто увидит. Однако давай посмотрим на это под другим углом. Подобная инициатива закладывает основу для саморегуляции и задаёт сообществу моральный ориентир. Мы получаем что-то вроде внутреннего кодекса чести и достоинства, который несмотря на негласность позволит каждому участнику видеть где пролегает граница допустимого. К тому же это позволит ощутить себя частью сообщества с определёнными ценностями.
Так мы можем наглядно показать, что является нормой для НАШЕГО общества, обсуждать это, формировать, и при необходимости ссылаться на прецеденты. В этом плане инициатива имеет огромный плюс, ведь она позволит нам создать рамки профессионального и уважительного общения, что укрепит репутацию и атмосферу ruSO.
И если модераторы продолжат содействовать в этом вопросе, мы сможем наглядно показать всему SO, что наше сообщество способно самостоятельно решать свои вопросы и имеет значимый голос на своей территории.
P.S. Всецело за инициативу +1

А где вы показывать что-то хотите? На мете? Ну, ей пользуются единицы. Новички так и вовсе про нее не знают. О каком показе "нормы" может идти тогда речь?) Также, о какой "самостоятельности" может идти речь, если для сброса этих ников нужен модератор? У нас, как у простых людей, в возможностях есть редактирование, так... Это сплотило людей? Я вон вижу чат "клуб редакторов" или что-то такое, где сидит 2-3 калеки и постоянно в пинг-понг играют, клево "объединяет", да) Ну а эта "инициатива" - это банальный "пшик", который через пару дней забудется. Да и смысл от него, если есть тревоги?

@EvgeniyZ Согласен, пока механизм далеко не идеален, но лучше что-то делать, чем просто обсуждать проблемы как это происходит в соседних темах о «спасении ruSO». Эта инициатива хотя бы даёт старт реальным действиям, а не бесконечным обсуждениям. Да, многое ещё можно доработать, и нужно чтобы больше людей участвовало. Но здесь важно, что модераторы готовы поддержать — и это уже шаг вперёд.

Понимаете в чем дело... 1. Если сообщество решит, что ник неприемлем, то это ничего не значит, ибо есть модератор, для которого это может быть нормой. Значит что? Правильно, голосование бесполезно (лучше просто список), ну и нужно разбираться с модераторами, ибо если там есть такие своевольные, то как вы построите нормальное сообщество? 2. Есть тревоги, надо приучать сообщество не списки составлять бесполезные, а кидать тревоги, ибо у нас сейчас такое просто пропускают. Ну а так, дайте мне знать через месяц об успехах данного крестового похода и как сильно он сплотил людей)

@EvgeniyZ Списки - это старт к активному саморегулированию и один из способов вовлечь сообщество в решение внутренних вопросов. Если инициатива не стухнет, то как знать, может сообщество увидит в этом некий знак, и инициатив, а вместе с ней и волонтёров станет больше. В любом случае от того что мы попробуем - хуже не будет. К тому же, данная инициатива уже на шаг ближе к решению проблемы, чем просто её игнорирование. Ведь в данной теме нам может помочь конкретный модератор, а в очереди тревог её может просто отменить равнодушный к вопросу другой модератор...

Не, я-то не запрещаю, дерзайте, вперед. Я лишь высказал свою точку зрения, даже минуса против не ставил. Просто я реалист, который видит в этом бесполезное, весьма странное действие, которое только нагружает модераторов охотой на людей, которые, наверно, даже ни разу не заходили на SO, ибо это скорей всего твины, либо боты. Ну а раз у нас даже "клуб редакторов" не смог объединить, то тут и подавно.
